# How to construct remote TenosrFlow session without starting a Server?

Tags: tensorflow

How can I construct a TensorFlow session that connects to an existing set of TF servers?

Following the [distributed TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed) guide I started a bunch of TensorFlow servers that are connected to form a cluster.

I would now like to start a session that can connect to those TF servers and assign ops to them. I assume I just need to specify an appropriate target in the constructor of tf session; e.g something like

```
with tf.Session(
    target, config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)) as sess:
```

However its not clear to me how to construct a target object pointing at any existing cluster of TF servers. The docs only show how to get the cluster spec from the server by calling server.target.

Do I need to start another server in order to construct a client that talks to the existing servers?

I want to connect to the TF cluster remotely. My TF servers are running on GCE VMs. I want to connect and assign ops to them from my local machine. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

For the target you can just use a string of the form

```
grpc://<host>:<port>
```

Where host and port are the hostname (or ip address) and port of one of the TF servers comprising the cluster. It doesn't matter which one because where an op executes depends on the device you assigned it to when you constructed the graph.